# How to make an Image in QML seem clickable by changing the mouse cursor?

Tags: qt, qml

So, I have a `QML` image which can be clickable. I want to show that it's clickable to the user by showing a `Qt.PointingHandCursor` on it. This is what I could come up with -

```
Image {
                source: "../images/a.png";
                height: 100; width: 100;
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    hoverEnabled: true;
                    onEntered: {
                        console.log("Hover entered");
                        cursorShape: Qt.OpenHandCursor;
                    }
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log("Image clicked");
                    }
                }
            }
```

However, when I enter the `MouseArea` of the `Image`, I get the log `Hover entered` but the cursor shape doesn't change. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following might help you. I don't think, that it is necessary for you to connect to any signals. Just set the `cursorShape` for the `MouseArea`.

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Image {
    id: image
    visible:true;
    source: "grapefruit.jpg";
    height: 100; width: 100;
    MouseArea {
        id: area
        anchors.fill: parent;
        hoverEnabled: true;
        acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton;
        cursorShape: Qt.IBeamCursor; 
    }
}
```